# How to add newline/linebreak in Quip Spreadsheet?

Tags: api, quip

I'm adding in data to my spreadsheet using:

```
client.add_to_spreadsheet(thread_id,*df)
```

... and it works, except it has ignored all my attempts to set any newlines. I've tried '\n', 'chr(10)', '<br>' and everything has been replaced by a single space.

How can I add a line break or newline?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself here in case it is helpful to anyone else in the future:
It turns out 
 works. Not sure why it didn't in the beginning but it does now.